# What is the spiritual logic behind 2 Corinthians 4:11?

Tags: 2-corinthians, death

2 Corinthians 4:11-12 NASB

> For we who live are constantly being delivered over to death for Jesus’ sake, so that the life of Jesus also may be manifested in our mortal flesh. So death works in us, but life in you.

How does being delivered to death manifest life in the flesh? And how does life become worked in the Corinthian church when Paul and his workers are being put to death in the flesh?
‭‭

Answer (score 2):

Op asked;
"How does being delivered to death manifest life in the flesh?"

> For we who live are constantly being delivered over to death for Jesus’ sake,

> so that the life of Jesus also may be manifested in our mortal flesh.

In order for the life of Jesus to be manifested in our mortal flesh something needs to occur first.  A death of something in order for His Resurrected life to be seen in our living mortal flesh at this time.  Paul gives an example of how this happened in him.

Paul's afflictions, were in a real sense the same sufferings of Christ, they came not because of his misdeeds  but because he was proclaiming the gospel of Christ.

> For  just as the sufferings of Christ are ours in abundance, 2:Corinthians 1:5

Christ was given over to death so that His Resurrected life could be given to the dead.  Christ has been unveiled in Paul. (Gal. 1:16). He too is being given over to death many times as he shares Christ's sufferings.

> For we do not want you to be unaware, brethren, of our affliction which came to us in Asia, that we were burdened excessively, beyond our strength, so that we despaired even of life; 9indeed, we had the sentence of death within ourselves in order that we should not trust in ourselves, but in God who raises the dead; 2:Corinthians 1:8,9

The scripture above I believe is the key to what Paul was dying to.  All the afflictions he went through is the vehicle to take him to the death of trusting in himself.  It was too great for him to bear in his own strength.  He died to looking to himself and instead looked to Christ to strengthen him where he could bear all things in him.
His reliance on Christ became life to him and showed up through his mortal body.

> But  we have this treasure in earthen vessels, that the surpassing greatness of the power may be of God and not from ourselves; 8we are afflicted in every way, but not crushed; perplexed, but not despairing; 9persecuted, but not forsaken; struck down, but not destroyed; 10always carrying about in the body the dying of Jesus, that the life of Jesus also may be manifested in our body.  2:Corinthians 4:7-10

Now to answer the second part of your question.
"how does life become worked in the Corinthian church when Paul and his workers are being put to death in the flesh? ‭‭"

> So death works in us, but life in you. 2
> Corinthians 4:12

Paul had died to his old way of life anger, bitterness and had been reconciled to God when he was his great enemy.

The forbearance, the affection, the patience, he had for the Corinthians showed up throughout his letter to them.  This truly was the life of Christ being manifested through Paul in light of how they were treating him.  The life of Christ was being revealed to them through
Paul.

> 2 Corinthians 12:15
> And I will very gladly spend and be spent for you; though the more abundantly I love you, the less I be loved.

I think they were being taught the grace of God which had first been shown to Paul through Christ and now that same grace of God is being shown to them.  Paul still loves them in spite of the way they treated him.  Is that not life?

Answer (score 1):

Paul was telling the Corinthians the difficult life they (Paul and his companions) were going through by preaching the Gospel of Jesus. For they had been hatred, beaten, and even stoned to death.

However, with the Spirit they never lost their heart, their own life was to demonstrate "*the light of the gospel that displays the glory of Christ, who is the image of God*" (2 Cor 4:4). Verse 11-12 means Paul and his companions were prepared to die for Jesus' sake, to manifest Jesus' life as to His disciples. That when they died, the Corinthians could live.

The crucifixion of the Christian during Nero period verified Paul assertion, as Christianity grew even stronger and not being eliminated.